# Random point on canvas path (path from svg)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

Im trying to put my svg path on canvas, like this:

```
this.svg = '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200" height="201" enable-background="new 299.9 155.9 200 200.9">...</svg>';
var mySrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(this.svg);
this.source = new Image();
this.source.src = mySrc;
ctx.drawImage(this.source, nv[0], nv[1], nv[2], nv[3]);
```

And that works fine

No what I want to do is to put a point (or circle) in a random location ON this path in canvas.
So I need to randomize x and y for this new point.

Is there any way to do it? How can i random puck an X coord, and then get Y coord so it lays on the path? The path is not a straight line.

Currently I'm not using any third party libraries, like Raphael but I can include them if needed.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok, i've came up with a quick solution, you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pg54qp84/
(hint: check the console for debug info)
But the problem is, i still need to do the initial animation, and depending on how fast it it, the number of points in points array will be different - the slower the animation, the more accurate representation of a curve in points array.

Does anyone have an idea on how can I get rid of this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SVG DOM [getPointAtLength(distance)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) method where distance would be a random number from 0 to [getTotalLength()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getTotalLength)

Comment: but what if the path is curved so it looks something like letter "C" or "O" - so it has two points with the same X ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you pick an X and get a Y. I'm suggesting you pick a random distance along the path and get that point's X and Y together thus avoiding any problems with duplicate Ys.